# Crating single npm package for both React (web) and React Native (Mobile)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an npm package. That package contains components related to react-native (View, Text, Stylesheet, etc ).

I would like to reuse the same package for my React JS (web) application.

I am stuck in the state where I am not getting any clue from the internet which gives me details about what are the changes I need to make in my react-native package so that I can use it in a web project as well.

I have tried using react-native-web npm. but it didn't work. Whenever I consume the package, am getting the error shown below

[image]

Did anyone try this way? Is there any good tutorial or approach to follow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use components written in react-native for web.
React libraries use HTML and CSS, so obviously they will not now how to display native components like View and Text.